# Returning a specific string format from an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of Persons (class contain name and lastname and id )
what I have to do is to return a string form this array but in a specific format an example will be more explicative

```
array=[PERS1,PERS2]
```

I need this as a return value : "The name of all  persons : "+ PERS1.name + PERS1.LASTN + " , " + PERS2.name +PERS2.LASTN +","

I know this method

```
 array.each{ |per|

                #but this will not return  the format ,and with each I think I can only    print (I'm new in the ruby field
                }
```

all of this because I need it when overriding to_s , because I  need to provide a string -> to_s

```
def to_s

    "THE name of all preson"+@array.each    #will not work as I want 
end
```

Thank you for ur  time and effort and if you need any clarification please let me know

Comment: In what class did you try to define this `to_s`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`each`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-each) just iterates over a collection and returns the collection itself. You may want to use [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-map) and [`join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.0/Array.html#method-i-join) the result.

```rb
array.map { |person| "#{person.name} #{person.lastn}" }.join(',')
```

Or if you modify your `Person` class it can be even simpler.

```rb
# I assume that the name of the class is Person and name and lastn are always present
class Person
  def full_name
    "#{person.name} #{person.lastname}"
  end
end

# Then you can call this method on `map`.
array.map(&:full_name).join(',')
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
array.each do |per|
 "#{per.name} #{per.LASTN}"
end
```

For more info check [Interpolation](http://ruby-for-beginners.rubymonstas.org/bonus/string_interpolation.html)